# get user group description and name in liferay

Tags: java, liferay-6

I want to get the user group description as well the name of logged-in user in portlet.
I am able to get the logged-in user object using:

```
    ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);  
    User user = td.getUser();
```

Please help me out with how to get the logged-in user's group.
These user groups are coming from ldap and mapped in liferay DB UserGroup.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: user.getGroup() will return a Group object, more details here: http://cdn.docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/User.html

Comment: If a user belongs to multiple groups, you should use getGroups() which will return a list of groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the user object, you can get full name of user by using

> user.getFullName()

for getting the user group description, call the following method, which will give you the list of Groups. which belongs to user.

`List <Group> grpList =    GroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroups(userId);`

Iterate the list to get the groupId's. Pass group Id to following method.

```
Group grp = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(groupId)
```

You can get group Description using

```
String grpDisc = grp.getDescription();
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I was asking about the userGroup not the group

Comment: I was asking about the userGroup. I have achieved that using  ThemeDisplay td = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);  
List<UserGroup> usrGrpList=UserGroupLocalServiceUtil(td.getUserId()); this will return the ldap user group to which the user are associated and by iterating over this list we can get the userGroup Name,Description.